# how to get column value for the next day in the same table

Tags: sql

My table contains data such as

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 100 |
| 2023-02-02 | 400 |
| 2023-02-03 | 749 |
| 2023-02-04 | 432 |

I want a new column which will take the value for the next day

| date | value | next day value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 100 | 400 |
| 2023-02-02 | 400 | 749 |
| 2023-02-03 | 749 | 432 |
| 2023-02-04 | 432 | 432 |

how to i get this result in SQL?

I have tried LEAD() function like LEAD(value) order by (date) but its not giving me correct value

Comment: only tag the database system  you are actually using

Comment: What's the expected result if there's a date gap?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: what is wrong with your result when you use LEAD ?

Comment: `lead()` will most certainly work for what you are trying to do. But without seeing your code it's impossible to tell what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it using `LEAD`.

`LEAD(expr [, N[, default]])`, N is the starting index (1 in our case ), and `default` is the value when null

```
select *, LEAD(value, 1, value) over (order by date) as 'next day value'
from mytable
```

This is working for most DBMS.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/kjJdRiLl)